# Multiple filled.countour plots in one graph

Tags: r, graph, plot, contour

I have a data frame containing continuous variable x, a factor y and a continuous variable z

For illustration assume

```
x <- 1:5
y <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")

z.a<-sort(sample(x=seq(0,1,0.1),size=5, replace=F))
z.b<-sort(sample(x=seq(0,1,0.1),size=5, replace=F))
z.c<-sort(sample(x=seq(0,1,0.1),size=5, replace=F))
z.d<-sort(sample(x=seq(0,1,0.1),size=5, replace=F))
z.e<-sort(sample(x=seq(0,1,0.1),size=5, replace=F))
```

Now i would like to construct the following plot

```
plot(x,y, yaxt="n", type="n",ylim=c(0,5),yaxs="i")
axis(2, at=seq(0.5,4.5,1), labels=c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"))
abline(h=0:5)
```

[image]

Now for each level of the `y` (displayed at the y-axis) i would like the box to be filled with color according to the respective z value. For example the the `A` of the plot should be filled with `z.a`, the `B` with `z.b`

All `z` contain values of same scale (0,1) and the are always decreasing with decreasing `x`

Is there any package that performs these kinds of plots? If no how can I code it in base R?

I would prefer a base R solution but if it is not possible any other solution will do.

Alternatively, the plot could be regarded as a horizontal barplot for each level of the y, ranging for the whole range of x and its color would be attributed to z (at each x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using `ggplot2` library.

First, put all your data into one data frame.

```
df<-data.frame(x = rep(1:5,times=5),
               y = rep(c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"),each=5),
               z= c(sort(sample(x=seq(0,1,0.1),size=5, replace=F)),
                    sort(sample(x=seq(0,1,0.1),size=5, replace=F)),
                    sort(sample(x=seq(0,1,0.1),size=5, replace=F)),
                    sort(sample(x=seq(0,1,0.1),size=5, replace=F)),
                    sort(sample(x=seq(0,1,0.1),size=5, replace=F))))
```

Then use `geom_tile()` to get colors for each level of `y` depending on `z` values.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df,aes(x=x,y=y,fill=z))+geom_tile()+
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) + scale_y_discrete(expand = c(0, 0))
```

[image]

#### UPDATE - solution using function image

Similar result can be obtained by function `image()` of base system.

First, put all `z` values in one data frame using function `cbind()`. Also made new x and y values.

```
z2<-cbind(z.a,z.b,z.c,z.d,z.e)
x2<-1:5
y2<-1:5
```

Plot `z` values using function `image()`. Then add axis with function `axis()`. To display legend function `image.plot()` from library `fields` is used. In both functions the same `col=` setting should be used. `image.plot()` can produce whole plot but this function doesn't allow to modify axis properly.

```
par(mar=c(5,5,5,8)) #sets space for legend on right side
image(x2,y2,z2,axes=F,col=rainbow(10))
axis(1,at=1:5)
axis(2,at=1:5,labels=c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"))
box()
library(fields)
image.plot(x2,y2,z2,legend.only=T,col=rainbow(10))
```

[image]

Comment: Updated my solution using function image().

Comment: Excellent. You are fantastic. I will probably use the base R solution. Could you please tell me how to code a legend key to map the z values to the colors (like the ggplot does automaticall)?